# Eventaddlistener is undefined Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I am trying to test the following code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refdInput.addEventListener("fieldInput", this.onChange);
    this.refdInput.addEventListener("fieldInput", this.onBlur);
    this.refdInput.addEventListener("fieldInput", this.onFocus);
  }

<input
  id="float-input-component"
  type="text"
  className={classes.join(" ")}
  ref={elem => {this.refdInput = elem;}}
/>
```

In spec.ts I have tried

```
var el = document.getElementById("float-input-component");
    el.addEventListener('fieldInput', onChange());
    el.addEventListener('fieldInput', onBlur());
    el.addEventListener('fieldInput', onFocus());
```

I get this error message TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, did you render your component before getting the element?

Comment: For that I tried fixing to put the jest code in windows.onload(){} method

Answer (score 0):

Because the addEventListener is called in the componentDidMount. In Jest the component should be mount (enzyme) instead of shallow or rendered

```
const renderedInputComponent = mount(...)
```